# Property 'detailed' does not exist on type 'Console'

Tags: typescript

i like to create my own console logs.

```
//-- Creating own console logs for better logging
console.detailed = function(payload) {
    return console.log(util.inspect(payload, { showHidden: false, depth: null }))
}

console.notice = function(payload) {
    return console.log('\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m', payload)
}
```

I just started with typescript and here I am getting error that

> Property 'detailed' does not exist on type 'Console'

or

> Property 'notice' does not exist on type 'Console'.

Can anyone please help me in solving the above error?

Update: From the answer by Saravana, Can someone explain me this as well in more human terms

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
>   top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file
>   without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a
>   script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore
>   to modules as well)." If your code is inside a module, you need to
>   wrap it inside global

And

> You might also need to wrap this inside the global scope if you are
>   using this inside a module. See
>   https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to extend the `Console` interface to add the new method:

```
interface Console {
    detailed: (payload: any) => void
}

console.detailed("works");
```

Note that if your [file is a module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) (i.e. it contains `import` or `export` statements), then you have to [declare this in the global scope](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) for this to work:

For example, if your file is a module:

```
import * as moment from "moment"; // This makes this file a module

declare global {
    interface Console {
        detailed: (payload: any) => void
    }
}

// Your actual method definition
console.detailed = (payload) => {
    console.log("Timestamp:", moment().unix());
    console.log(payload);
}

// Usage
console.detailed("works");
```

Comment: Saravana, Can you explain this line? **You might also need to wrap this inside the global scope if you are using this inside a module** with some example?

Comment: @anny123 Read [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). _"In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well)."_ If your code is inside a module, you need to wrap it inside `global`.

Comment: Saravana, Firstly I so appreciated you answering this question. I have started the bounty on this since I am still not sure on wrapping it inside global store, secondly I was also curious about the project structure. I am updating the question as well. Would love if you can make it simple as if there is an absolute beginner. Thanks again