# How to import and use javascript node modules in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase

In my code I am using javascript firebase module

```
const FirebaseStore = require('connect-session-firebase')(session)
```

What should be the correct way to import it and use it in typescript?

Comment: Also, If someone can look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813002/property-detailed-does-not-exist-on-type-console

Comment: Go with this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-session-firebase

Comment: @GauravKandpal wats with the link?

Answer (score 0):

There're two aspect to your question, syntax-wise and configuration-wise.

### 1. syntax

The preferred module syntax in TypeScript is esModule style:

```
import ... from ...
```

So the preferred module syntax for your code would be:

```js
// you can rename it whatever you like:
import connectSessionFirebase from 'connect-session-firebase'

const FirebaseStore = connectSessionFirebase(session)
```

### 2. configuration

Fact check: the runtime module system in Node.js is CommonJS style.

```
require(...)
```

So when TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript, you need to configure it correctly to connect the bridge between both worlds.

Below is the recommended compiler configurations, for it's most error-tolerant. I'll explain one by one.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

#### `"module": "commonjs"`

**This option affects code emit**. It's **required** for `tsc` to emit JS code for a runtime env that uses CommonJS module system, which in you case is Node.js. Basically it tells TS to perform these transformation:

```
// input:
import * as lodash from "lodash"   // case 1
import express from "express"      // case 2
import React, { Component } from "react" . // case 3

// output:
var lodash = require("lodash");
var express_1 = require("express");
var react_1 = require("react");

var express = express_1.default;
var React = react_1.default;
var Component = react_1.Component;
```

#### `"esModuleInterop": true`

**This option affects code emit**. It's **optional** but recommended. It adds two runtime compatibility helpers `__importDefault` and `__importStar`. They convert CommonJS module to pseudo ESModule on the run.

For details of these helpers check this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wDYQCZoBZwBmUEIcARFrqnuQFCiSxwCmAHmFC6usaRe07dU9RtHgAlFsgDGMADRwA3nADCpSADsWm+AF8iJMuS6yY9OjIibU8APpwAvJhz5L123DuCuPJ6w5fVHcbeykzf3C5EM87dXBrHXhneK0koA).

#### `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

**This option DOES NOT affects code emit.** It only affects TS type checking behavior, and it's meant to be used together with `"esModuleInterop": true`. Turning this option on will allow you to default-import a none-ESModule module.

Example, famous `express` lib is CommonJS-only module, it does not have a default export.

```
// allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false
import * as express from 'express' // good
import express from 'express'      // error

// allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true
import * as express from 'express' // good
import express from 'express'      // good
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should install `Connect Session Firebase` which I assume you have done.

If you have not, run: `npm install firebase-admin connect-session-firebase --save`

---

Now that `Connect Session Firebase` is installed you can start using it.

You also need a middleware... I prefer using the **[Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#readme)** middleware with firebase, you can also use **[Express](http://expressjs.com/)**.

Installing connect is quite easy just like firebase : `npm install connect`

---

Using `Connect Session Firebase`

```
const connect = require('connect');
const FirebaseStore = require('connect-session-firebase')(connect);
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const ref = firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert('path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json'),
  databaseURL: 'https://linkToDatabase.com'
});

connect()
  .use(connect.cookieParser())
  .use(connect.session({
    store: new FirebaseStore({
      database: ref.database()
    }),
    secret: 'secret'
  }));
```

Comment: the question description mentioned it but not the title. I mean, In typescript?

Comment: @anny123 You can use js in typescript, typescript is just a superset of js that compiles down to normal js

Comment: is that an optimal way?

Comment: @anny123 As ive mentioned above, there is not much to requiring npms and then using them. As typescript compiles down to js. So going the "standard" route is fine.